# Friend Group and Hater Group

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Consider a set $S$ of $n$ people such that, for all distinct $x$ and $y$ in $S$, it is the case that
either $x$ and $y$ like each other or $x$ and $y$ hate each other. Let us call $S' \subseteq S$ a friend group if, for all distinct $x$ and $y$ in $S'$, $x$ and $y$ like each other, and let us call a $S' \subseteq S$ a hater group if, for all distinct $x$ and $y$ in $S'$, $x$ and $y$ hate each other.

Let us deﬁne $R(k)$ as the smallest natural number such that in every set $S$ of $R(k)$ people, there is either a friend group or a hate group of size $k$. For example, $R(2) = 2$.

(a) Prove that $R(3) > 5$.

(b) Prove that $R(3) \leq  6$. (Together with the previous part, we have $R(3) = 6$.)

(c) Prove by induction that $R(k) \leq 2^{(k(k-1))/2}$ for all $k \geq 2$.

I'm having incredible difficulty with this question. I believe that you need to use the generalized pigeonhole principle in solving this but I really am stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you modeling the situation using graphs? I would think you can do (a) and (b) by brute force.

Comment: The problems are arranged in order of difficulty, from easiest to hardest. I'd advise taking them one at a time, and doing the easier ones first--you've got to walk before you can run. So what have you done with (a)? (If that's still too hard, make it even easier by trying to prove $R(3)\gt4$ first.)

Comment: For part (a): to have one simple example that $R(3)>5$, model $5$ people by the corners of a pentagon. Then let a line connecting two points correspond to a mutual friendship, and not being connected by a line to being mutually haters. Then connect the pentagon in the standard way. Then no set of three points are connected (no triangle), so no size $3$ friend group exists. On the other hand any group of three points contains a pair of friends/a pair of adjacent corners so no size $3$ hater group exists either.

Comment: What you are searching for is called the Ramsey's Theorem. Here is the link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem